# Play 2.4.x: Stuck forever at Generating https key pair on https launch

Tags: java, https, playframework

I ran the command for default https launch as

> app.bat -Dconfig.resource=config.file -Dhttps.port=9443

However my server gets indefinitely stuck at

> play.core.server.ssl.FakeKeyStore Generating https Key Pair, may take
>   few minutes...

and few minutes never end. Any idea what causes this? I found an old post on this too, but that too had no answers.

Further, how do I find the server logs for the launch? There are no files in the logs folder under stage so, sorry if that sounds silly but I have no idea where to look for the logs.

Thanks for taking time out for this. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is stuck? There will be no log statement when it's done (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9a06b9a0a6ea7d1299e61ea3c1f37a08b714297e/framework/src/play-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/ssl/FakeKeyStore.scala#L58). Also, have you tried simply generating a certificate yourself as a workaround?

Comment: Yes. It looks like stuck to me. I also found another unanswered question on the same issue here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/play-framework/kg45_Uf9u6E . The code has no confirmation on generation of the key pair successfully but I could see the file of 4KB on server. Still no progress on the launch. Not sure why?

Comment: dev/random need entropy to work. If entropy is empty on your machine dev/random will wait for it... As long as it takes.
You can check available entropy by command `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`

Anyway there is a tool [Haveged](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haveged)